# sybase while loop assistance

Tags: sql, loops, sybase

I have a basic understanding of SQL and Sybase, this is the first time I have tried to loop something. I tried several suggestions here, and put together the following

```
 DECLARE @district varchar(2), @numSchools int, @sc_cd varchar(2)
 SELECT @district = 'MS', @numSchools = 1

 SET rowcount 0
 SELECT supv_clas_cd INTO #MyTemp
     FROM t_supv_class
     WHERE eff_dt IS NULL

 DECLARE @rowsaf INT
 SELECT @rowsaf = @@rowcount FROM #MyTemp

 WHILE @rowsaf > 1
 BEGIN
     SET rowcount 1
     SELECT @sc_cd = supv_clas_cd FROM #MyTemp
     SET rowcount 0
     DELETE #MyTemp WHERE @sc_cd = supv_clas_cd
     SELECT @rowsaf = @@rowcount FROM #MyTemp

     SELECT TOP @numSchools
         s.nm_tx AS 'School Name', @sc_cd AS 'Supv Class'
        FROM t_Schools s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
        WHERE supv_clas_cd = @sc_cd
        AND s.csrv_cd = @district
 END 
 SET rowcount 0
```

What I am attempting to do is avoid a large number of UNIONs where only the "supv_clas_cd" changes.
Basically, return a set number of school names for each given supv_clas (which can change as the table is editted).

The temp table #MyTemp has, on average, 40 rows within it.
Not all combinations of "supv_clas_cd" and "crsv_cd" have values, but TRY/CATCH does not seem to hope.

Can anyone help me get this loop working? Or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Or just hard-coding all the supv_clas_cd and union the result the better solution in class than trying to loop all this?

My original idea was/is
    DECLARE @district varchar(2), @numSchools int
    SELECT @district = 'MS', @numSchools = 1

```
SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'CC'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'CH'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'CO'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'CT'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DA'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DB'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DI'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DJ'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DM'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DS'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'DV'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'FB'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'FO'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'LC'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'LH'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'LL'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'LN'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'LT'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'MC'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'MH'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'ML'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'MN'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district

UNION

SELECT TOP @numSchools
    s.nm_tx
    FROM t_Schools s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_supv_class sc ON sc.supv_clas_cd = s.supv_clas_cd
    WHERE supv_clas_cd = 'MT'
    AND s.csrv_cd = @district
```

This assumes that "WHERE supv_clas_cd" does not change, and if I need to change the SELECT statement I have to do it in each and every location.

A sample of the data looks something like

```
t_supv_class|t_Schools

supv_clas_cd|nm_tx            supv_clas_cd
CC          |Acidlog    DB
CH          |Alexander  FB
CO          |Amazing     CT
CT          |Arthur  FB
DA          |Babel   CT
DB          |Babica FB
DI          |Bambleweeny    DB
DJ          |Bang   CH
DM          |Beeblebrox CT
DS          |Beneath    CH
DV          |Betelgeuse DB
FB          |Blagulon   CT
FO          |Blaster    CH
LC          |Both   DB
LH          |Brain  CH
LL          |Bugblatter CH
LN          |By CH
LT          |Clare  DB
MC          |Cos    CH
MH          |Could  CH
ML          |Damogran   CT
MN          |Dark   DB
MT          |Deep   CH
```

and from this sample, I would want

```
Acidlog
Alexander
Amazing
Bambleweeny
Bang
```

I was thinking of looping so centralize the SELECT statement for maintenance and reusable, as well as not hard-coding all the values of t_supv_clas.supv_clas_cd.

For the record, I have only read-only access to the database, so I cannot create a procedure (which was another thought I had).

Comment: sql doesn't function well on loops (the best example I can give you for this...you want to drive 10 miles, so you want to get in the car and drive it in one trip. Looping in SQL is the equivlent of stopping every 50 feet to rebuild your car from the ground up). You want as close to one statement to do all as possible. Before continuing on this route, you should ask yourself if you can achieve these results without a loop? It's hard to tell from whats here, but if you gave a little sample data and an example of the results you want, I'm sure we can find a loppless sql solution for you.

Comment: You can do this with an APPLY operation or by using the row_number() function. No loop or cursor needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure how you expect to see "Bambleweeny", maybe I've misunderstood something, but "Bambleweeny" is associated with the supv_class_cd "DB", as is "Acidlog".

To acheive the result and to allow @numSchools to influence the number of rows returned for each supv_class_cd, I needed to create a "dense rank". In Oracle and SQL Server I believe
there is such a keyword, but in Sybase ASE there isn't, so it's faked here:

```
            (
                select
                        count(*) as row_id
                    from
                        t_schools s1
                    where
                        s.nm_tx >= s1.nm_tx
                    and s1.supv_class_cd = t.supv_class_cd
            ) as row_id
```

The count(*) counts the number of rows that are less than the current row and match the supv_class_cd column in the consolidated outer table, #MyTemp. In this case, the dense rank is over the nm_tx column.

The set of supv_class_cd values in #MyTemp is iterated over using a join, this replaces the looping in the original question.

```
    select
            s.nm_tx,
            s.supv_class_cd,
            (
                select
                        count(*) as row_id
                    from
                        t_schools s1
                    where
                        s.nm_tx >= s1.nm_tx
                    and s1.supv_class_cd = t.supv_class_cd
            ) as row_id
        from
            t_schools s,
            #MyTemp t
        where
            s.supv_class_cd = t.supv_class_cd
```

Finally there are the original parts of the question to add in

- the outer join with t_supv_class which is simply what was specified
- the limit on the number of rows per supv_class_cd
- creation of #MyTemp, again specified
- declaring and setting of parameters

.

```
declare
    @numSchools int,
    @district char(2)

select
    @numSchools = 1,
    @district = 'MS'

select distinct 
        supv_class_cd
    into #MyTemp
    from t_supv_class
    where
        eff_dt is null

select
        x.nm_tx as School_name,
        x.supv_class_cd as Supv_class        
    from
    (
        select
                s.nm_tx,
                s.supv_class_cd,
                (
                    select
                            count(*) as row_id
                        from
                            t_schools s1
                        where
                            s.nm_tx >= s1.nm_tx
                        and s1.supv_class_cd = t.supv_class_cd
                ) as row_id
            from
                t_schools s,
                #MyTemp t
            where
                s.supv_class_cd = t.supv_class_cd
    ) x
    left outer join t_supv_class sc on sc.supv_class_cd = x.supv_class_cd
    where
        x.row_id <= @numSchools
go
```

I hope this finds you in good time, or at leasts provides you with some help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following statement which occurs twice a little odd:

```
SELECT @rowsaf = @@rowcount FROM #MyTemp
```

I would use :

```
SELECT @rowsaf = count(*) FROM #MyTemp
```

`@@rowcount` is a system variable that stores the number of records affected by the most recent executable command. It's not related to count of rows in a table.
See if this brings you closer to desired result. A `UNION` statement with 1 sql per code value is definitely not recommended.